# Confusion with in-built toLower function

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, functional-programming

I am using VSCode as my IDE for Haskell on a Mac.

This simple function

```
toLowerSt :: String -> String
toLowerSt = map toLower
```

returns the following error:

```
Main.hs:92:17: error:
    • Variable not in scope: toLower :: Char -> Char
    • Perhaps you meant ‘toLowerSt’ (line 92)
   |
92 | toLowerSt = map toLower
   |                 ^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I struggle to understand what the actual problem here is. A string is mapped into chars yet it's throwing me this error.

Comment: Yes yes yes. I was scratching my hear around which library to import with no luck. Seems to be a general for-all. Resolved, thanks.

Comment: To resolve this, I simply Googled `haskell toLower`. That lead me [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:toLower), and from there, you can see that it's in the `Data.Char` library if you scroll up to the top.

Comment: For the future, `Variable not in scope` means the compiler can't see a definition of that variable. That means you need to look for typos in the name (either here, or where you defined it), or you need to import it from somewhere.

Comment: You can use [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=toLower) to search the module you need to import. Hoogle reports it's in the `base` package (so you don't have to install anything, it comes with Haskell itself) and the `Data.Char` module (which you need to import).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [**`toLower :: Char -> Char`** function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:toLower) is defined in the [**`Data.Char`** module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.2.0/docs/Data-Char.html) and not re-exported by the `Prelude`, you thus need to import this with:

```
import Data.Char(toLower)

toLowerSt :: String -> String
toLowerSt = map toLower
```